# how to add case condition in sql to calculate sum if there is column(weight) of type varchar and data is numeric or null or NA

Tags: sql, sybase, rapidsql

```
select stick,sum(convert(float,weight)) as total
from lod_description group by stick
```

above query works fine but when null or NA comes in the weight field as data it gives error as varchar to int not allowed

Expected Result:

```
 stick  | total 
oldstick 10.01 
newstick 20.034
```

Comment: Why did you tag with MySQL if you're actually using Sybase?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen new to the Data base stuff some one told me tag it in mysql

Comment: which Sybase RDBS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? the 4x products do not share a common SQL dialect so knowing the actual product (and to a lesser extent version) will help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming OP's current query works for everything *except* when `weight` is NULL or `='NA'`, how about:

```
select stick,sum(convert(float,weight)) as total
from   lod_description
where  weight is not NULL
and    weight != 'NA'
group by stick
```

If this is Sybase `ASE`, `SQLAnywhere` or `IQ`:

```
select stick,sum(convert(float,weight)) as total
from   lod_description
where  isnumeric(weight) = 1
group by stick
```

**NOTE:** I don't know if Sybase `Advantage` has a comparable function but shouldn't be too hard to review the associated reference manual to find out.

And if OP is set on using `case`:

```
select stick,
       sum(case when isnumeric(weight)=1
                then convert(float,weight)
                else 0.00
           end) as total
from   lod_description
group by stick

-- or

select stick,
       sum(case when weight is NULL or weight = 'NA'
                then 0.00
                else convert(float,weight)
           end) as total
from   lod_description
group by stick
```

Comment: the issue is that only weight column defined is varchar which i cant change and values are all numeric and if we get NA/null it should return case or value as 0 for rest convert function will take care and will return original value looking for a query with case condition

Comment: @M.R.K did you try the queries using `isnumeric()` and if so what issue didn't they address; I've also updated the 2nd half of the answer with a couple more `case` options

Comment: tired both the mention query 1st one add up 100 in total weight sum and 2nd one given me same error

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your `weight` column should be numeric, and not text.  You could sum a `CASE` expression which returns 0 in the event that `weight` be a non numeric string.

```sql
SELECT stick,
       SUM(CASE WHEN weight REGEXP '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$'
                THEN CAST(weight AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) ELSE 0.0 END) AS total
FROM lod_description
GROUP BY stick;
```

Comment: it gives me error as (incorrect syntax near REGEXP) and weight column is defined as varchar in DB

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: neither this or the ops 'working' code syntax https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f584e433320fbd99a95f5cae2ef3d51c specifically the convert syntax..

Comment: also correct syntax is convert(expr,type) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f692bf1dabd9150dcb67f890d2b6c4e

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is sybase database and rapid sql as tool

Comment: @P.Salmon it is a working code above query was working fine unless i got a bug some one entered 'N.A' and null in the weight field

Comment: @M.R.K sybase is not the same as mysql , you should tag correctly if you want useful comments and answers..